Is there a way for a node to have multiple connection to its edges?
In my application, nodes contain a list of text values, and I want the edges which relate to those values to connect to the node such that they point directly at that part of the node
          +-----------+
          | Name      |
          +-----------+
 ------->o| A         |
          +-----------+
 ------->o| B         |
          +-----------+

I haven't been able to find a way to do this, searching around online and after reading the docs, and would like to know if its possible. I also perused the available extensions without any luck. Thanks

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
